# Is it faster to prepend to a string with substr?

Tags: perl, benchmarking, substr, micro-optimization

I just found code that prepends with `substr( $str, 0, 0, $prepend )`

```
my $foo = " world!"
substr( $foo, 0, 0, "Hello " );
```

Is this any faster than

```
my $foo = " world!"
$foo = "Hello $foo";
```

Answer (score 5):

## Optrees

If we compare the two optrees the top has

```
b     <@> substr[t2] vK/4 ->c
-        <0> ex-pushmark s ->7
7        <0> padsv[$foo:2,3] sM ->8
8        <$> const[IV 0] s ->9
9        <$> const[IV 0] s ->a
a        <$> const[PV "Hello "] s ->b
```

While the bottom has

```
8     <+> multiconcat(" world!",-1,7)[$foo:2,3] sK/TARGMY,STRINGIFY ->9
-        <0> ex-pushmark s ->7
7        <0> padsv[$foo:2,3] s ->8
```

## Benchmarking

I've created a quick benchmark for this,

```
use Benchmark;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub b_multiconcat {
    my $foo = "world!";
    $foo = "Hello $foo";
    return $foo;
}

sub b_substr {
    my $foo = "world!";
    substr( $foo, 0, 0, "Hello " );
    return $foo;
}

sub b_substr_lvalue {
    my $foo = "world!";
    substr( $foo, 0, 0 ) = "Hello ";
    return $foo;
}

unless ( b_multiconcat() eq b_substr() && b_substr() eq b_substr_lvalue() ) {
    die "they're not all the same";
}

Benchmark::cmpthese( -3, {
    multiconcat   => \&b_multiconcat,
    substr        => \&b_substr,
    substr_lvalue => \&b_substr_lvalue
} );
```

And the results that I got are,

```
               Rate              substr    substr_valute   multiconcat
substr         7830854/s            --          -18%          -24%
substr_lvalue  9606148/s           23%            --           -7%
multiconcat   10288066/s           31%            7%            --
```

So we can see the multiconcat saves a few ops and is somewhat faster. It also looks a lot nicer to say,

```
$foo = "Hello $foo";
```

Comment: @hobbs yes I did. hobbs++ (since fixed)

Comment: How is 4-arg substr slower than lvalue substr (which must create a magical scalar, and requires extra operations)???

Comment: Tip: Using `-MO=Deparse,-exec` instead of `-MO=Deparse` provides a more accurate representation of what is executed a run-time.

Comment: @ikegami is it slower for you too? It's a good question, but that seems to be the case for me.

Comment: Closer, but yeah

Comment: The comparison will not be complete without `$foo = 'Hello ' . $foo;` included into the test.

Comment: @Polar Bear, That generates the same code as `$foo = "Hello $foo";`, so there's no point in benchmarking it

Comment: @ikegami - on my laptop it gives 3% improvement in comparison with `$foo = "Hello $foo";`. The difference, it does not require _interpolation_ of variable (only _concat_).

Comment: @Polar Bear, Again, they both generate EXACTLY the same code (a `multiconcat` in new versions, a `concat` in older version), so neither can possibly be faster than the other. 3% is well within the margin of error.

Comment: @ikegami I would be interested in hearing exactly why the substr in LHS is faster, because I assumed as you did too, that it would be slower and involve more magic. For that purpose, I created a question about it feel free to tell if you happen to have already investigated this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61670492/124486

Comment: Remember that the Benchmark module has an uncertainty of about 7%. See Dumbbench for a better tool (and read Steffen's [various blog posts about it](http://blogs.perl.org/users/steffen_mueller/dumbbench/)).